# Access a array that contains object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs

I try to access data from a prop

Like `this.props.teachers` it retrieves me `Object {}` on console and when I try `this.props.teachers[0]` returns undefined and `this.props.teachers[0].age` retrieves an error because cant access undefined ?

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Here's the code snipet

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var helpers = require('../utils/helpers');

var ResultList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
     return{
        usersDataArr:{},
     }

    },
    componentWillMount : function() {
        helpers.getAvaiabilityResults(this.props.params.places,this.props.params.branch,this.props.params.dayOfMonth,this.props.params.timeStart,this.props.params.timeEnd)
        .then(function(data){
            this.setState({
                usersDataArr:data.AvaiabilityResults
            })
        }.bind(this))


    },
    render: function(){
                return(

            <div>
                ResultList
                <Results teachers={this.state.usersDataArr[0]} />
           </div>
            );
    }
});
var Results = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.log(this.props.teachers);
    },
    render: function() {

        return (
            <h1>Results</h1>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = ResultList;
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: I think you lost `this` somewhere, the access to array item is works just fine:

`var a={a: [{test: 1}]};console.log(a.a[0].test)`

Comment: the problem was that the data wasn't loaded until both componnent mounts.  Thanks to GreenJello on IRC 